# IIS 7.5 Windows Authentication Not Working in Chrome

Tags: iis-7, webserver, authorization, intranet

On a new installation of IIS 7.5 I have setup Windows Authentication on my Intranet.

The providers I have used are 'NTLM' and negotiate in that order.

This works fine in IE and Firefox but in chrome I get the following

> This web page is not available
>   The web page at http://mysite.com/myintranet.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   Error 338 (net::ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS): Unknown error.

I've tried looking online for a solution without any success.

I'm running the latest version of Chrome 21.0.1180.60

Comment: Perhaps [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) is a better place for this.

Answer (score 22):

Remove 'Negotiate' provider. Can't tell details, but had the same issue. Reordering doesn't help.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Just one of those weird MS things - it doesn't make sense that you have to remove "Negotiate" if they are (supposedly) ranked. But, indeed, this did solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting the same issue in chrome for a default web site which I brought up to handle forwarding default port 80 traffic to a sharepoint site. Chrome handles the FQDN of the sharepoint site, but when I navigate directly to the root web, chrome shows me no love.

I fixed the issue by creating a simple default.htm file with a good ole fashioned meta redirect.

HTH!