# Microsoft Edge Issue - The requested resource requires user authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-edge, iis-8.5

I have a website and api hosted on `IIS 8.5` and lately users of the site are getting the following console error when attempting to `POST` data to the api when using `Microsoft Edge`:

> HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
>   (XHR)OPTIONS - http://**my-local-address**/api/customers/approval/post

**Note:** Users are authenticated by using Windows Authentication.

This occurs spontaneously and to get around the issue the users are forced to do a hard refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) on MS Edge and then they can continue with their process. Could there be a setting on `IIS` that's releasing the user authentication after a period of time?

I've listed my attempts to resolve the issue below:

- I've got my organisation to add in a trusted policy for my local web address.
- Changed the providers of the API. Moved **NTLM** above **Negotiate**.
- Removed **Negotiate** based on this stackoverflow post [Windows authentication failing in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694162/windows-authentication-failing-in-iis-7-5).
- Try and catch the error from the `POST` request but I'm returning **null** every time.
- Configured `CORS` to allow for cross origin.

**NB:** I'm using `angularjs` for my front end and `ASP.NET Web API 2` for the API.

The following code snippet details how the Web Api is configured:

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

**Web.config**

```
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
     <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Angular module config using `$httpProvider` to supply `$http` requests with credentials**

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: Also having this issue on Edge 18/IE11 on Windows 10 with an Angular 5 application.  I can log in fine on all other browsers

Comment: @ChrisBarr did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same issue as you

Comment: @sbattou sorry but no - best we could figure is that it was an issue with "secure cookies" not being set up properly on my dev machine... but we never really looked into it any farther

Comment: @ChrisBarr was it working properly on other peoples machines?

Comment: I think so... I am the newest developer at my organization and there is not a well documented setup process yet, so we might have missed something.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I just posted a question if you want to check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405714/windows-authentication-not-showing-login-popup-when-not-authenticated-on-edge-an