# IIS WIndows authentication not working for other users in the same domainRSS

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have published a website which uses Windows authentication and it is working for the machine on which the site is deployed. When any other users in the same network try to access the website, it will prompt for credentials again and again and not allowing the user to access the site.

In IIS NTLM is used as the provider for Windows authentication.

What is the root cause behind this issue?

Comment: Read IIS log files to learn what is the status/sub status code https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: As lex says, you should firstly get the details error log, then we could find the solution according to the error log's details information. You could find it in the IIS's logs and the event viewer. Besides,I suggest you could try to follow this [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31438781/7609093) suggestion to solve your issue.